# macro in makefile? Conditional h-file inclusion?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Let me explain my situation:
I have a program that contains different kinds of models (let's say 10, but the actual number is quite high). All these models have a name and corresponding file "model1.cu" and "model1.h". All of these files have a function that produces one float number and returns it, which is in all files named the same, with the same arguments (let's say `float returnfunction(float voltage)`). This particular function is needed in the main file.
In the makefile I have put an option such that you compile only the code for the model you will be calculating with as follows:

```
ifdef MODEL1
SRCS := model1.cu
OBJS := model1.o
endif

ifdef MODEL2
SRCS := model2.cu
OBJS := model2.o
endif

SRCS += main.c
```

Now I can select the correct model by typing "make MODEL1=1". The problem arises in the main-file. The function `returnfunction(float voltage)` is defined in model1.h, so I should include it. But when I include

```
#ifdef MODEL1
#include "model1.h"
#endif

#ifdef MODEL2
#include "model2.h"
#endif
```

in my main.c file, I get the error that the function `returnfunction` is not defined anywhere.
Is there a way to get the correct h-file included in my main-file? Preferably by using that I already compile by using MODEL1 = 1.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: By the way, a cleaner way to do this is to put each model in a separate subdirectory, with files named e.g. `model.cu` and `model.h`. Set `VPATH` and add a `-I` flag from your makefile, then you can set `SRCS := model.cu`, `OBJS := model.o` and generically `#include <model.h>` in your `main.c`.

Comment: I like your idea, but could you specify on the use of VPATH and -I? I'm not familiar with all possible options in a makefile and the documentation is often very difficult to understand for me.
What I would like to know is the lines you would put in the makefile (Assume the map is called: NewModel and it contains model.cu and model.h)(the rest of the concept I get). Is it something like: #ifdef MODEL1 VPATH = -I ./NewModel #endif ?

Comment: Too long for a comment, so I wrote an answer for that, it basically drops every `ifdef` you have in there. It's just a suggestion, the accepted answer will fixing your posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a preprocessor definition to your Makefile, for each model you have. For example, in the case of MODEL1=1:

```
ifdef MODEL1
SRCS := model1.cu
OBJS := model1.o
CFLAGS += -DMODEL1
endif
```

Assuming you are using the [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), the modified `CFLAGS` will be passed to every file that is compiled. If you've used your own rule to compile main.c (and aren't using `CFLAGS`), then you could create a variable, and pass it in explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is to the point and fixes your missing `#define`. I'll expand on the comment I left on a cleaner/DRYer way to do this.

The first piece is having each model in its own directory, with common source/header names. For example:

```
├── models
    ├── model1
    │   ├── model.cu
    │   └── model.h
    ├── model2
    │   ├── model.cu
    │   └── model.h
    └── ...
```

(you might drop the top-level `models` directory, doesn't matter)

We're going to play with include paths, so you can drop the whole `#ifdef` stuff from your `main.c` and replace it with a single `#include <model.h>`.

Next, let's be a bit smarter with how we specify the model. Instead of having `MODEL1`, `MODEL2`, etc. let's use a generic `MODEL` variable which takes the model name, so the make command will look like `MODEL=model1 make` (if having separate vars is a hard requirement there are ways to do it without tons of `ifdef`s, but it's still uglier).

At this point writing the Makefile becomes trivial:

```
SRCS := models/$(MODEL)/model.cu main.c
OBJS := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRCS)))
CFLAGS += -Imodels/$(MODEL)
```

I don't know how you're handling `SRCS` and `OBJS` later on in the Makefile so I just used `addsuffix` and `basename` to slap a `.o` in there, but you can change it to your needs. I add the model directory to the include paths via `CFLAGS` so that it'll pick up the right `model.h`.

You could also specify sources like this:

```
VPATH := models/$(MODEL)
SRCS := model.cu main.c
```

Since make will look into `VPATH` for sources.

Some misc stuff: if you still need a C `#define` you can add it via `CFLAGS`. If you have some common stuff in your `.h` files consider refactoring it into a top-level `.h` which then `#include <model.h>`. If your compiler supports it, `#include_next` might also be handy.